# Why does a generic call to a stored procedure throw an exception under load? Is procedure not thread safe?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

**UPDATE** 
Once I looked into the variable ii and saw it was a class variable I was able to move it to be defined in the method and all worked correctly.  I'm 95% convinced this is due to multiple threads updating ii at the same time.  Would someone be able to explain that behavior for me?

My library method has been working for a couple of years, but recently has been throwing a System.IndexOutOfRangeException and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  I've set a breakpoint at the in the catch block and figure out that ii is set to 5, but it should never get to 5.  The parameters are a ReturnCode that has a direction of ReturnValue.  The next and last 3 have a direction of Output.  The spParams has 3 parameters.  The only thing I can think of is it's got something to do with threads, but could really use some help debugging what's going on here.  It works for the same call if I resend it also.

```
    public DataSet GetDataSetFromStoredProcWithObjectParams(string spName, object[] spParams)
    {
        // First Create a New Connection
        using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            sqlConn.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand()
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                CommandText = spName,
                Connection = sqlConn,
                CommandTimeout = iSqlCommandTimout
            };

            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

            // Assumption here is that sp param list order matches object list order.
            try
            {
                ii = 0;
                for (var idx = 0; idx < cmd.Parameters.Count; idx++)
                {
                    if (cmd.Parameters[idx].Direction != ParameterDirection.ReturnValue && (cmd.Parameters[idx].Direction == ParameterDirection.Input || cmd.Parameters[idx].Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput))
                        cmd.Parameters[idx].Value = spParams[ii++];
                }
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Stored Procedure being processes is: " + spName);
                for (var j = 0; j < spParams.Length; j++)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Stored procedure Parament " + j + " is " + spName[j]);
                }
                log.Error(ex);
                throw (ex);
            }

            // Create an Adapter
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var ds = new DataSet();

            // Fill The DataSet With the Contents of the Stock Table
            da.Fill(ds);
            return (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0) ? null : ds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `ii` a field? Why isn't it local? Anyway, step through in a debugger or put in traces for everything. Find out what's happening when. If threads are involved, traces will disturb things less than the debugger.

Comment: Dump `cmd.Parameters`, at least name and direction, in your `catch` block. It clearly doesn't agree with `spParams`, but are you sure you know which is wrong?